# Bash history not saved after closing terminal

Tags: bash, history, ubuntu-gnome, bash-history

I recently replaced my Ubuntu 14.04 installation with Ubuntu Gnome (which comes with Gnome DE). But I noticed that bash history is not saved once the terminal session is closed. Once I close a terminal session and open a new one, and run the command `history` it does not show anything other than the `history` command itself. Is there any way to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: did you figure this out? if not, paste your profile/rc here for review.

Answer (score 84):

It may be that your .bash_history doesn't belong to your user. Check the permissions of the file and if you're not the owner, change it:

```
sudo chown yourusername:yourusername ~/.bash_history
```

Comment: Worked for me. Curious how that happened though.

Comment: Same here. I also wonder why that happened?

Comment: Shouldn't you set the group as well, with `sudo chown yourusername:yourusername ~/.bash_history`?

Comment: Boombaa ! 
I take this moral from the story: "When such basic facility fails (and by default is ON), then most likely this is due to famous "permissions: problem." :)

Comment: This fixed the problem for me too.  I strongly suspect that sudo -s was the problem but it does not happen every time.  I note that -s leaves the home dir as the original.   I was using that before my history vanished.

Comment: it happened to me once. There was blank permissions block. `chmod 0644 .bash_history` solved the problem "-rw-r--r--"

Answer (score 26):

First type following command

`shopt -s`

to check weather `histappend` command is 'on' or 'off'
If it is off then type following command to append history

`history -a`

If you want to save history with every new prompt run following command

`export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`

For more information see [this](https://superuser.com/questions/555310/bash-save-history-without-exit) link

Comment: `histappend` is 'on'. Can't figure out what's going on. :/

Comment: I think some pipe connecting to history file is broken ,because if from terminal history is append then only it can be case of broke pipe try reparing or reinstalling system if you can

Comment: `histappend` isn't even listed in the output of `shopt -s` even tho `$HISTSIZE` and `$HISTFILESIZE` are set properly.  Idea?  Thanks!